# elementary OS 5.0 Juno doesn't start after sleep

Tags: greeter, release-juno, suspend, laptop, shutdown

I have installed elementary OS 5.0 Juno on my laptop and after a while working , when I actually leave it in sleep mode , it doesn't starts normally. The only way I could turn on was to shut down ( using the power button ) and then turn it on.

Comment: I think your pc dosen't like suspend mode or Hibernate mode

Comment: Can you try understanding where is the problem in the suspend process? This may help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/16239/how-to-debug-suspend Most probably this is a driver issue, may you update the question with brand/model of your laptop?